# How to send a mail from Mail palette in TIbco Designer?

Tags: tibco

I am trying to send a mail from Mail palette in Tibco Designer.I have set host name as smtp.gmail.com:587 but i am getting error as "**BW-MAIL-100024 Job-6000 Error in [Sender.process/Send Mail] Could not resolve mail server host name [smtp.gmail.com]**.". Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

On command line of the same machine (local desktop or server), run "nslookup smtp.gmail.com".

You should have a problem finding an IP address.